# How do I export an ElGamal key to a text file?

Tags: python, encryption, rsa, pycrypto, elgamal

I've been working on encrypting a string and displaying it as a QR code (after base64 encoding the string).

I want to use the ElGamal private-public key encryption module in PyCrypto for the encryption, but the problem is that it has no export function to save the key to a text file. Am I missing something? And if not, is there a clever way that I can export it, or something else that I should look at instead?

PS. The reason for using ElGamal and not RSA is that I can make the keys smaller than 1024 bytes, which makes for a smaller, less complicated qr code.

Comment: El-gamal key sizes are not shorter than RSA. You should look into ECC (elliptic curve cryptography) for shorter asymmetric key size.

Comment: Just a quick help for googling this: The name of this algorithm actually is "ElGamal". Note the 'a' instead of 'e'.

Comment: 768-bit keys have already been broken, and brute force attacks just get faster all the time. 1024 bits is the bare minimum nowadays for any security at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use access the ElGamal key components directly, since they are member of the key object.

In Python 2.x, one could do the following to print out the components in a text file:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import ElGamal
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes

key = ElGamal.generate(2048, get_random_bytes)
comps = ('p', 'g', 'y', 'x')
out = "\n".join(["{} = {}".format(comp, getattr(key, comp)) for comp in comps])
print out
```